# Environment variable is not setting globally

Tags: linux, csh

I am using `csh` terminal.

.cshrc

```
setenv $files /home/ec2-user/files
```

.login

`if [ -f ~/.cshrc ]; then
     . ~/.cshrc
fi`

I am trying to echo **$files** values from plink.
It showing the error **files: undefined variable**

Comment: Use export files=/home/ec2-user/files instead

Comment: Don't use `csh`. Try [zsh](http://zsh.org/). Read [csh considered harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)

Comment: @RamanSailopal, this is csh, not bash or posix. `export` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a dollar sign when setting a variable, you only use it when you refer to that variable.

```
setenv files /home/ec2-user/files
```

The `test` command should be a built-in in most csh/tcsh implementations, and has most of the same functionality you'll see listed under `man test`.

```
test -f ~/.cshrc && source ~/.cshrc
```

Note that normally, csh/tcsh will run your `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` file automatically, before it runs `.login`.